# Visual Studio Setup Deployment Project - How to Specify File System Installation Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project, setup-deployment

How do I specify Default Location of where my Product is to be installed and create additional folders for Log Files, Temporary Files?

For instance, if I decide to install every instance of my application in the path

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\ is where I want to install my Application, that is, the DLL's, Executables all need to be there.

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\\LogFiles is where I want to write the Log Files.

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\\Temporary Files is where I want to write the Temporary Files that my program will generate (and delete thereafter)

So, I want my Setup to create the main folder and the sub-folders.

In addition, I want to write my AppName.exe.config in a way, that it points to the above created sub-folders.

How do I achieve the same.

My Environment Details:

Visual Studio 2008
C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not appropriate paths.  Your app needs to go into c:\program files\manufacturer\productname.  Your temporary files need to go into Path.GetTempPath so that they'll get cleaned-up when your app crashes and forgets to clean up the temporary files.  Find the directory at runtime.  Your log files need to go into c:\documents and settings\username\application data\ folder.  Find the directory at runtime with Environment.GetFolderPath().  Don't store paths in app.exe.config

This ensures your app will install and run on any Windows version.

Comment: Thanks! Any particular reason as to why I should not use the App.exe.config for storing paths? Also, if I have to set the Log Folder at a path Environment.GetFolderPath(), how will I set it using log4net? Apologise that I have not included that in the question. Will update it right away.

Comment: Please don't change your question.  I gave you a proper answer on your original one.  Start a new question about log4net.

Comment: Apologies. I updated the question before reading your comment. I have rolledback to the original question. But, can you still provide me with some info on why App.exe.config shoud NOT be used for this?